# What has happened to this statement " auto iter = first"

Tags: c++, iterator, constants, auto

What has happened to this statement:

```
auto iter = first;
```

Why `iter++` can work well, as we all know, `first` is `const&`,

```
template<typename iteratorT, typename valueT>
iteratorT find(const iteratorT& first, const iteratorT& last,const valueT& value)
{
    auto iter = first;
    while(iter != last && *iter != value) iter++;
    return iter;
}
```

Why?

Comment: Type deduction: you are getting a non-const copy of `first`.

Comment: if i do not want to use auto, what should i do ,thank you

Comment: Use `const iteratorT&` or `const auto &` instead if you want it to be a const reference.

Comment: `decltype(first) iter = first;`, now you get a `const&` one.

Comment: Or `decltype(auto)`. There, saved one letter.

Comment: Btw, why pass iterators by `const&`?

Comment: Honestly, i have no idea about this, I am a beginner, and i am not a English native speaker, I am learning English,  so I am sorry for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how type deduction works when using `auto`, in the example you are getting a copy of `first` and that copy has type `iteratorT`.

You can use instead:

- `const iteratorT &iter = first`
- `const auto &iter = first` (or just `auto &`)
- `decltype(first) iter = first`
- `decltype(auto) iter = first`

All of them if you want `iter` to be a const reference, of course.

Thanks to @songyuanyao and @LogicStuff for theirs suggestions in the comments.

---

Consider also the following example that reproduces your issue in a cleaner way:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    int i = 42;
    const int & j = i;
    auto k = j;

    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(k), int>::value, "!");
    static_assert(not std::is_same<decltype(k), const int &>::value, "!");
}
```

Comment: if iter is a const reference, how "iter++" can work well,

Comment: @z_chong That's why I said - _All of them if you want `iter` to be a const reference, of course._ It looks like that was your intent from the question, apart for the fact that it would have been broken the code, of course.